# Nunit 3: Test a Controller that uses IHttpClientFactory as Constructor Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

**Update 20221024**: I have used Ruikai Feng's solution in order to use Mockoon with my tests. I realize this is not a correct approach from a unit testing approach and am working to change my approach.

**Update 20221019**: I have been using moq to mock out the IHttpClientFactory. The reason why I wanted to instantiate it was to call mock apis created in a tool called Mockoon which replicates apis. I have been so far unable to call these APIs likely because I have not yet properly mocked the ihttpclientfactory. I appreciate all the feedback as the solution is still ongoing at this time.

I am using a .NET 6 Web API controller with IHttpClientFactory to perform external API calls. As such, I have the following constructor:

```cs
public MyController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
  _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}
```

This works because in my `Program.cs` I add an HTTP Client to my `builder.Services`.

In my tests, how do I instantiate/set up the `httpClientFactory` for the controller because I need it to instantiate my controller: `var controller = new MyController(httpClientFactory);` generates an error since there isn't any settings added.

I ran into a similar issue with configurations from appsettings.json and resolved with `ConfigurationBuilder` but there doesn't seem to be a similar one for `IHttpClientFactory`.

If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity why did you mark a solution proposal as the answer which is fundamentally wrong from unit testing perspective?

Comment: Hello Peter, I hope this following explanation is sound. I was using that solution to communicate with a mock API tool, Mockoon, that can be embedded in my test chain. Within the tool I can create mock API endpoints that replicate the same calls as the API I am testing with several cases. In my test cases, I use this method in my SetUp() and test against each endpoint testing one method and assert the specific values and parameters. The reason I am using Mockoon is to remove dependency on calling the actual API endpoint itself and call the mock one instead.

Comment: That's an integration test, where you mock your downstream http service(s). If you want to perform integration testing then crafting a `ServiceCollection` by hand is suboptimal. If you want to perform unit testing then you need to Mock the `IHttpClientFactory` and all related stuff, just as I described in my proposed solution.

Comment: I appreciate your help Peter! I have chosen your solution and will be working on implementing this mocking into my unit tests and use the previous effort/proposed solution for integration tests. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use a properly mocked `IHttpClientFactory` in your unit test you need to do the following steps:

#### Setup a `DelegatingHandler` mock

```
var mockHandler = new Mock<DelegatingHandler>();
mockHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
    .Verifiable();
mockHandler.As<IDisposable>().Setup(s => s.Dispose());
```

This sample mock will always return with 200 OK status code and without a response body

- Tailor the setup for your needs

#### Create an `HttpClient`

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object);
```

It creates an `HttpClient` instance and pass the above handler to it

#### Setup an `IHttpClientFactory` mock

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockFactory
  .Setup(factory => factory.CreateClient())
  .Returns(httpClient)
  .Verifiable();
```

It setups an `IHttpClientFactory` mock to return the above `HttpClient` for the `CreateClient` method call

- If you use the `IHttpClientFactory` to create a named client then change the `Setup` to this `.Setup(factory => factory.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))`

#### Use the mock objects for verification

```
mockFactory.Verify(factory => factory.CreateClient(), Times.Once); 
mockHandler.Protected()
   .Verify("SendAsync", Times.Once(), It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to amend [@Peter CSala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13268855/peter-csala)'s answer some, since it got me most of the way there but not entirely. My service class uses the `IHttpClientFactory` but without any named client. When setting up the above code and running as is, I'm met with an exception:

```cs
Message: 
    System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: factory => factory.CreateClient()
    Extension methods (here: HttpClientFactoryExtensions.CreateClient) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

  Stack Trace: 
    Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) line 87
    ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, MethodExpectation& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 234
    ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 149
    Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Func`4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 643
    Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) line 498
    Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression) line 452
    MyServiceTests.GetHttpClientFactoryMock(Int64 contentLength) line 84
    MyServiceTests.DoesCopy_PutObject() line 55
    GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
    AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
    TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
    TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
    DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

This is because the parameter-less call to `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient()` is actually an extension method, where the method call for a named client is not. Looking into the extension method, it actually is [just a convenience wrapper](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3565f599a12daf14b86c075db8ec0745d022bddf/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/HttpClientFactoryExtensions.cs#L22C14-L22C14) for the named client method using a default name from `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`.

All you have to do is actually mock the named client method to return the mocked `HttpClient` from Peter's example above when requesting the default name. Here is the entire code I used to mock the `IHttpClientFactory` to work with a default client and workaround the above exception:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var mockHandler = new Mock<DelegatingHandler>();
mockHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    .Verifiable();
mockHandler.As<IDisposable>().Setup(s => s.Dispose());

var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object);
var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockFactory
    .Setup(factory => factory.CreateClient(Options.DefaultName))
    .Returns(httpClient)
    .Verifiable();

// Use the factory from above in your tests
// Calls in the service to IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient() will
// return the HttpClient using the mocked handler from above :)
var res = myService.DoTheThing(mockFactory.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class IndexActionTests
    {
        private HomeController controller;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var httpclientfactory = provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            controller = new HomeController(httpclientfactory);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var result = controller.Index();
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ViewResult),result.GetType());
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 1. Create a DI container 2. Register the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` into it 3. Retrieve the factory to inject it via ctor. << You should **not** do these steps in a unit test. You should **mock** the dependencies not re-create them. With your setup the `HomeController` will issue a real HTTP request, which is not the intent of a unit test. It is more closer to an integration or e2e test.